# nodejs sending mails with images in the background

Tags: node.js, email

I want to send mails simething like this [image]

Right now I am using nodemailer and  email-templates to do the job but I am unable to design a template with an image and a logo in the background. I also read about sendgrid, but I do not know how to transfer an image.
Any help or ideas of what I should look for

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for embedding images into email template. You can do that with simple HTML, Inline CSS, and Table layout for designing  a email template along with nodemailer.
I have used Node.js and Express.js framework.

```
 router.get('/api/check',function(req,res){
    var user = "Saurabh";
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: 'Gmail',
                    auth:{
                        user:config.central_email,
                        pass:config.central_email_password
                    }
                });    
                var MailOptions = {
                    from: 'Johnson Tiles<apps@hrjindia.in>',
                    to: 'saurabh@sattvarise.com',
                    subject:'Welcome to Sattvarise Technologies -  Augmented Reality Workshop',
                    text:'Welcome to Sattvarise Technologies. We offers market-leading expertise in the latest 3D, Augmented Reality and Virtual Reality for Android, iOS, Google Cardboard, GearVR and more.',
                    html:'<div style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#F8F8F8;border:1px solid #ddd">   <img src="cid:image1@johnson.com" width="100%">   <div style="height:1%;"></div>   <div style="border-radius:5px;text-align:justify;padding:15px;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #888888;background-color:#FFF;margin:0 auto;font:16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:1.5;color:#848484;"> <b>Hello '+user+',</b><br>      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome to Sattvarise Technologies.   We offers market-leading expertise in the latest 3D, Augmented Reality and Virtual Reality for Android, iOS, Google Cardboard, GearVR and more..      <br><br>      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0 auto;border-bottom:1px solid #cee3ed;padding:0;background-color:rgba(236,240,241,0.3);">  <caption style="font-size:20px;color:#005999;font-weight:bold;background:rgba(236,240,241,0.3);border-top:1px solid #cee3ed;">How to use</caption>         <tbody>            <tr>               <td width="60"></td>               <td width="160" valign="middle">                  <div style="padding:0 0 0.5em;color:#699bbf;font:bold 16px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"><img style="border: 1px solid #cee3ed" src="cid:image2@johnson.com" width="130px"></div>               </td>               <td width="16"></td>               <td width="364" valign="top" style="padding:1.5em 0">                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;color:#8d9ba6;font:15px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:1.5">                     <tbody>                        <tr>                           <td width="24" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:4px 0 0;font-weight:bold;color:#005999">1.</td>                           <td valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0 0 1.25em">                              <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#005999" target="_blank"> Download Android app from google play store</span><br>                              <span style="font-size:13px"><a href="#" style="color:inherit;">Play store link</a></span>                           </td>                        </tr>                        <tr>                           <td width="24" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:4px 0 0;font-weight:bold;color:#005999">2.</td>                           <td valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0">                              <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#005999" target="_blank">Download and Print</span><br>                              <span style="font-size:13px">Download and print adjacent image on A4 paper (Either Color/Black & White print).</span>                           </td>                        </tr>                        <tr>                           <td width="24" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:4px 0 0;font-weight:bold;color:#005999">3.</td>                           <td valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0">                              <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#005999" target="_blank">Place the Marker</span><br>                              <span style="font-size:13px">Place the printed image on the Floor</span>                           </td>                        </tr>          <tr>                           <td width="24" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:4px 0 0;font-weight:bold;color:#005999">4.</td>                           <td valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0">                              <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#005999" target="_blank">Transform your space to luxury</span><br>                              <span style="font-size:13px">Open Johnson Tiles AR app and go to "Transform your space to luxury".</span>                           </td>                        </tr>           <tr>                           <td width="24" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:4px 0 0;font-weight:bold;color:#005999">5.</td>                           <td valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0">                              <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#005999" target="_blank">Scan the Marker</span><br>                              <span style="font-size:13px">As camera feed opens in the app, scan the printed image and it will show tiles on top of it. </span>                           </td>                        </tr>          <tr>                           <td width="24" valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:4px 0 0;font-weight:bold;color:#005999">6.</td>                           <td valign="top" style="margin:0;padding:0">                              <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#005999" target="_blank">Select tiles from the catalogue</span><br>                              <span style="font-size:13px"> Use other features from the right panel for a complete experience.</span>                           </td>                        </tr>                     </tbody>                  </table>               </td>               <td width="60"></td>            </tr>         </tbody>      </table>   </div>   <hr>   <div style="height:3%;"></div>   <div>      <div style="height:90px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">         <span style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;color:#8d9ba6;font:20px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;line-height:1.5;margin-right:50px;">Follow us on</span>         <a href="http://www.youtube.com/hrjohnsonindia1" target="_blank"><img width="28px" src="cid:image3@johnson.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://twitter.com/Hrjohnsonindia" target="_blank"><img width="28px" src="cid:image4@johnson.com"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.facebook.com/HRJIndia" target="_blank"><img width="28px" src="cid:image5@johnson.com"></a><br>         <div style="height:15px;"></div>         <a style="color:#E42C33;padding:5px;background:#F8F8F8;" href="http://www.hrjohnsonindia.com/" target="_blank">http://www.hrjohnsonindia.com/</a>      </div>   </div></div>',
                    attachments:[{
                        filename : 'kat-banner-bg.jpg',
                        path: './public/images/kat-banner-bg.jpg',
                        cid : 'image1@johnson.com'
                    },
                    {
                        filename : 'FINAL_MARKER.jpg',
                        path: './public/images/FINAL_MARKER.jpg',
                        cid : 'image2@johnson.com'
                    },
                    {
                        filename : 'youtube.png',
                        path:   './public/images/youtube.png',
                        cid : 'image3@johnson.com'
                    },
                    {
                        filename : 'twitter.png',
                        path: './public/images/twitter.png',
                        cid : 'image4@johnson.com'
                    },
                    {
                        filename : 'facebook.png',
                        path: './public/images/facebook.png',
                        cid : 'image5@johnson.com'
                    },
                    {
                        filename : 'JOHNSON_MARKER.jpg',
                        path: './public/images/FINAL_MARKER.jpg',
                    }]
                }
                transporter.sendMail(MailOptions,function(error,info){
                   if(error){
                       console.log('Email Error '+error);
                   }
                   else{
                       console.log('Email Sent to user '+info.response);
                       res.json({Message : "Email is sent to user"});
                   }
                });
});
```

In above example, all the images are in public folder of express.js framework.
In **attachments** option, you need to pass array of images that are going to embed in email. **cid** is used for embedding images.
Example :

```
{
       filename : 'facebook.png',
       path: './public/images/facebook.png',
       cid : 'image5@johnson.com'
}
```

and to use that image in nodemailer use

```
<img width="28px" src="cid:image5@johnson.com">
```

Comment: do we need to follow the same naming "cid" name like an email id ?

Comment: No it is not required to name "cid" like email_id, you can name it like "image1". It is like variable for image which is used as source in HTML template.

Answer (score 1):

> Any help or ideas of what I should look for

Look for HTML email templates. Designing HTML emails is quite different than designing HTML for websites. For emails you often have to use tables for layout and other tricks that has been forgotten in web design. Look for HTML email templates, read about HTML email formatting, and if everything fails then you may need to put the text into images for certain cases.